# Regex to extract words that contain three vowels

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a function to extract the words that have 3 consecutive vowels form the below strings

```
import re
def three_vowel_words(text):
     pattern =  "[\w]+[aeiou]{3}"
     result = re.findall(pattern, text)
     return result

print(three_vowel_words("Our team was victorious over theirs in the contest."))
#the output should be ["victorious"]

print(three_vowel_words("Obviously, the acquaintance is serious and ambitious.")) 
#the output should be ["Obviously","acquaintance","serious","ambitious"]
```

However the output I am getting is as follows:

```
["victoriou"]

["Obviou", "acquai", "seriou", "ambitiou"]
```

Can someone help me correct my regex pattern so it will extract the full words.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it `"\w+[aeiou]{3}\w+"` that way the rest of the word is also matched. With your current solution the matching stops when the 3 consecutive vowels found.

**EDIT:** As it was pointed out by @usr2564301 and @Tomerikoo a more general way would be `"\w*[aeiou]{3}\w*"`. This way words which start or end with 3 vowels or just having only 3 vowels are also will be matched.

Comment: Better but now there *must* be another letter after any series of 3 vowels. Your *cadeau* works for OPs small sample set but not for other words.

Comment: maybe `(\w+)?` might be more general

Comment: @leena Glad it helped. See the edited part also. And thanks for usr2564301 and Tomerikoo for the observations/suggestions.

Comment: Well-deserved upvote because I actually missed the *first* `\w+`; now it also matches *eau* (if you'll pardon my French, again – can't think of an English word that starts with 3 vowels). @Tomerikoo, for GREP `(\w+)?` is as unnecessary as OPs suggested `[\w]` ...

Comment: @usr2564301 wow you're so right! I think I got too much stuck inside the box trying to expand on existing code that I couldn't see the obvious fix. Thanks for the eye-opener. I'm considering deleting that comment from embarassment but will leave it for future readers

Comment: Thank you all for your great inputs.